# Как выровнять слайд в карусельке по центру страницы

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4, позиционирование, карусель, центрирование

Для создания карусельки я использовала bootstrap.

```
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

Но мне надо, чтобы сам слайд был не на всю ширину блока, а имел определенный размер, в CSS задала след свойства

```
.w-100 {
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 760px;
}
```

Остается расположить сам слайд по центру страницы, но у меня не получается. Когда я заданию позицию **left:50%;** в родительском блоке **carousel-inner**, у меня слайд вообще съезжает в другую сторону. Свойство **transform: translateX();** тоже не помогло выровнять элемент по центру.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант можно добавить center-block в class к img:

```
<img src="..." class="d-block w-100 center-block" alt="...">
```

У меня на данном коде карусельки, это размещает слайд по центру не зависимо от его размеров.

еще как вариант можно использовать:

```
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```

для элемента img

Comment: не помогло( надо, чтобы слайд находился строго между стрелочками, по середине страницы.

Comment: о) теперь заработало! спасибо большое